# Ember Data isn't seeing my local store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Full Disclosure: I am new to Ember.

I have an app that I have started where when the user clicks on the next button, they create an instance of the customer model and that model is saved to local storage.  On the next page, I want both the first and last name to pre-populate the text inputs. I have tried to follow the [intro video](http://emberjs.com/guides/) but I have run into a problem.  It appears that I am creating the object and then storing it successfully in local storage, but when the user transitions to the next page, the model can't be found. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div id="nobox" class="navbar-inner">
              <div class="container">
                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </a>


              </div>

          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">

        {{outlet}}

        <footer>

        </footer>

      </div>
    </body>



  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="container main-container" id="main">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <!--<div class="progress-bar-label-div">
                            Progress: 
                        </div>
                        <div class="progress-bar-div">
                            <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                <div class="bar" style="width:60%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="captcha" {{action 'create'}}>
                                Next
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="messages">

                </div>
                <div class="row top">
                    <div class="pull-left" >
                        <h3 class="purple">To start the process, please fill out the captcha below</h3>

                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="pull-left questions">




                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>





            <hr>
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customer">

  <div class="container main-container" id="main">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                            {{#linkTo 'wsnum' action="create" classNames="btn btn-primary"}}Next{{/linkTo}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="messages">

                </div>
                <div class="row top">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <h3>Customer Information</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row top">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <span class="red">*</span> = Denotes required field
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right form-inputs input-text">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row-b">

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputfname">First Name<span class="red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="controls">

                          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='model.first'}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-a">

                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputlname">Last Name<span class="red">*</span>:</label>
                        <div class="controls">

                          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='model.last'}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

            </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="prev" value="">




            <hr>


  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="wsnum">

  <div class="container main-container" id="main">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <!--<div class="progress-bar-label-div">
                            Progress: 
                        </div>
                        <div class="progress-bar-div">
                            <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                <div class="bar" style="width:60%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <!--<a class="btn" href="">
                                Prev
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="captcha">
                                Next
                            </a>-->
                            {{#linkTo 'customer' classNames="btn btn-primary"}}Prev{{/linkTo}}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="messages">

                </div>
                <div class="row top">
                    <div class="pull-left" >
                        <h3>Choose the Number of Workstations or Point of Sale Accessories only</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="pull-left additional-questions">
                            How many workstations will you need?
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right input-text-well">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="pull-left additional-questions">
                            Request Point of Sale Accessories only
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right radio-wsnum">
                            <label class="checkbox inline radio-new-pos">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="posonly1" name="posonly1" value="pos"> POS only
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>





            <hr>


  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="overview">


  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="new">


  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="existing">


  </script>
```

And my app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.LSAdapter.extend()
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.route("customer", { path: "/customer" });
  this.route("wsnum", {path: "/wsnum"});
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  create: function(){
    var customer = App.Customer.createRecord({
      first:"ron",
      last:"testing"
    });
    console.log('Before the save');
    customer.save();
    console.log(customer.get('first'));
    this.transitionToRoute('customer');
  }
});
App.CustomerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    var customer = App.Customer.find();
    console.log(customer.get('first'));
    return customer;
  }
});

App.WsnumRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

var attr = DS.attr;
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  first: attr('string'),
  last: attr('string')
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/efiqap/2/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App.CustomerRoute.model()`, this line:

```
var customer = App.Customer.find();
```

sets the `customer` variable is being set to result of `find()`. `find()` returns an array of all customer records. So when you call get('first') on the array it is undefined, since the array of customers does not have a property `first`.

Also, the route

```
this.route("customer", { path: "/customer" });
```

should probably be:

```
this.route("customer", { path: "/customer/:customer_id" });
```

since it seems to be for displaying one customer not a list of them.

With that change, `CustomerRoute` is not really needed at all. So app looks like:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.LSAdapter.extend()
});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("customer", { path: "/customer/:customer_id" });
  this.route("wsnum", {path: "/wsnum"});
});
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  create: function(){
    var controller = this;
    var customer = App.Customer.createRecord({
      first:"ron",
      last:"harmon"
    });
    customer.save().then(function() {
      controller.transitionTo('customer', customer);
    });
  }
});

var attr = DS.attr;
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  first: attr('string'),
  last: attr('string')
});
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/itogeh/1/edit